# Firefox cursor information colour black letters

Tags: mouse, color-format

[image]

When the cursor is not moving and that frame appears and normally it's black and the letters are white. After the update yesterday it is completely black. I have the default firefox theme, just after the update yesterday it shows this way and I can't read anything. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Fore added some code in the stylesheet a few hours ago to fix this. *(thanks by the way ;)*

You can add these 2 lines by yourself in your `gtk-widgets.css` or wait for an system update.

The file is in your system folder... `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/`

And the changes you can find here...

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-design/egtk/4.x/revision/541

to see the changes click on... **>** expand all